# In Firefox, the element with positive rotation angle is on top

Tags: html, css

I have two images on my page with perspective applied and a rotation angle. The images are absolutely positioned and overlap each other slightly. For now one of the image (Image B) is on `rotateY(0deg);` the other one (Image A) has `rotateY(15deg);` and on hover it goes to `rotateY(-15deg);`.

The problem is when the angle of Image A is 15deg, it's behind Image B but on hover when angle changes to -15deg it overlaps Image B. It doesn't happen in Chrome. I've tried anti aliasing methods and preserve-3d and everything else I could think of. What could be the reason for this behavior in Firefox?

[image: Image A under Image B][image: Image A over Image B]

Edit: Here's some code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="phone-container">
   <img id="htc" src="img/htc.png">
   <img id="samsung" src="img/samsung.png">
</div>
```

And Css:

```
#phone-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    perspective: 500px;
}
#phone-container #htc{
    width: 42%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -138px;
    transform: rotateY(15deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
#phone-container #htc:hover{
    transform: rotateY(-15deg);
}
#phone-container #samsung{
    width: 44%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-right: -139px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I've added the code to my question. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved that whith **`translateZ`**.

The unit of `translateZ` is pixels and you have to move the Z axis of the element behind, above the rotated element.

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
#phone-container #samsung{
  width: 44%;
  position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: -139px;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(__px);
                                      ^ Your desired pixels
}
```